# Comparing fields of 2 documents from same collection to produce a diff

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a system that
I wish to produce history of changes that happened to the documents in a collection at a particular timestamp

So let's say we have a document in a collection

```
[
  {
    "property1" : "A",
    "property2" : "B",
    "createdAt" : "2023-05-18T06:36:00.000+00:00"
  }
]
```

which gets changed to:

```
[
  {
    "property1" : "A1",
    "property2" : "B",
    "createdAt" : "2023-05-18T07:36:00.000+00:00"
  }
]
```

then for createdAt value `"2023-05-18T07:36:00.000+00:00"` I wish to produce output like

```
[
  {
    "propertyChanged" : "property1",
    "oldValue": "A"
    "newValue": "A1"
  }
]
```

Still trying to figure the aggregate pipeline operators best for this

Comment: Will the same document get updated or a new one will be inserted into the db?

Comment: Similar to @CharchitKapoor - how will you be getting the old document in order to compare with the new document? Will it be stored in another collection or are you doing a `find` then comparing that result with a proposed update?

Comment: Hi @CharchitKapoor the new document would be inserted

Comment: Hi @jQueeny ,
The new document would be in the same collection .  I wish to find what changed in 2 consecutive documents when sorted by createdat field.

Answer (score 0):

How about something along these lines:

1. Use `$match` to filter the documents based on the timestamp

   ```
   db.collection.aggregate([
     {
       $match: {
         createdAt: "2023-05-18T07:36:00.000+00:00"             }
     },

      //2. Use lookup to perform a self-join on the collection to find the previous version of the document based on the createdAt field.
     {
       $lookup: {
         from: "collection",
         let: { createdAt: "$createdAt" },
         pipeline: [
           {
             $match: {
               $expr: {
                 $lt: ["$$createdAt", "$createdAt"]
               }
             }
           },
           { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
           { $limit: 1 }
         ],
         as: "previousVersion"
       }
     },
     //3. Use unwind to destructure the arrays from the last operation
     {
       $unwind: "$previousVersion"
     },

     //4. Finally you can use project to compare the fields
     {
        $project: {
          propertyChanged: {
            $setDifference: [
              { $objectToArray: { $arrayElemAt:      ["$previousVersion", 0] } },
              { $objectToArray: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$ROOT", 0]    } }
            ]
         }
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$propertyChanged"
    },
    {
      $project: {
        propertyChanged: "$propertyChanged.k",
        oldValue: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          { $objectToArray: { $ifNull: ["$previousVersion", {}]    } },
          { $indexOfArray: [ { $objectToArray: { $arrayElemAt: ["$previousVersion", 0] } }, "$propertyChanged.k" ] }
          ]
        },
        newValue: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          { $objectToArray: { $ifNull: ["$$ROOT", {}] } },
          { $indexOfArray: [ { $objectToArray: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$ROOT", 0] } }, "$propertyChanged.k" ] }
          ]
       }
     }]);
   ```

Comment: Hi  @ChidiEkuma  ,
Thanks for replying
I tried this aggregate pipeline and this works fine till the last stage where we are projecting to get the output .
In the last stage i'm getting following  error

$arrayElemAt's first argument must be an array, but is object

Comment: @LakhanSINGH I've updated the solution Let me know if it resolves your errors

Comment: Hi @ChidiEkuma,
so just before step number 4 where we are unwinding $previousVersion
it turns previousVersion into an object now inthe first  $project stage in step 4 ,
we cannot use it as an array in the following line

{ $objectToArray: { $arrayElemAt:      ["$previousVersion", 0] } },

I'm getting the same error now at this line 

error:
$arrayElemAt's first argument must be an array, but is object

Comment: @LakhanSINGH, I updated the original code but forgot to tag you.